# Multi-Variable File Naming Convention

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, filenames

Heyo! I am trying to change the filenames of all of the pictures in folder to a new naming schema so that a program I am using can recognize it. the current naming schema is 'cam1_###.png' where the ### is the number in the sequence. For example, the first photo is named, "cam1_000.png".

What I am trying to get to is the following naming schema: 'cam1_r###_####_rgb.png' where the 'r###' and the '####' increases by one everytime. For example, the first image in the folder, 'cam1_000.png", would be renamed 'cam1_r000_0000_rgb.png' and the 100th photo would be renamed from 'cam1_099.png' to 'cam1_r099_0099_rgb.png'

I feel like this should be super easy, but I'm having trouble with the formatting :/ here is what I currently have:

```
files = os.listdir(".")
i = 1
for file in files:
   os.rename(file, file + 'r_'+i+'_'+i+'.png')
   i = i+1
```

Thanks in advance for any advice/redirection!

Comment: @jpp thanks for the heads up! Marked yours ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trying using [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to make your output filename easier to define. You can also use [`str.zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) to provide the necessary zero-padding.

In addition, you should use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for a counter.

Finally, it's useful to split the name and extension from your filename using [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext).

```
for i, file in enumerate(sorted(files), 1):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
    os.rename(file, '{0}_r{1}_{2}.{3}'.format(name.split('_')[0], str(i).zfill(3),
                                              str(i).zfill(4), ext))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) here. You create a string representing the pattern you want to use, and then call the `format()` method of that string with the value(s) you want to substitute in as arguments.

In this case, I think you could use

```
"{0}r_{1:03d}_{1:04d}.{2}".format(base_filename, i, extension)
```

In the format code `{1:03d}`, the `1` tells it which argument to `format()` to use (zero-indexed, so `1` means the second argument, `i`), and the part after the colon tells it how to format that argument: `0` means include leading zeros, `3` means fill up three characters, and `d` means to format it as an integer.

Note that you'll first need to split the filename into the base (e.g. `cam1_000`) and extension (`png`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb, so this is what I got... hopefully, this will help anyone else trying to do this :D

```
files = os.listdir(".")
i = 0
for file in files:
  alpha="%03d" % i
  beta="%04d" % i
  os.rename(file, 'cam1_r'+alpha+'_'+beta+'_rgb'+'.png')
  i = i+1
```